# How does rollback work on soft updates

Tags: freebsd

I've been reading a paper on [soft updates](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=Soft+updates%3A+a+solution+to+the+metadata+update+problem+in+file+systems&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=) recently and it discusses rolling back changes to avoid dependency cycles. The point of doing this is because ["we have to write to the disk in block-size units, and each block can potentially contain metadata affected by more than one metadata operation"](https://lwn.net/Articles/339337/).

So I understand what is happening now and why we have to perform this action but I'm stuck on the understanding the process of how the rollback actually works in practice. I understand that soft-updates are currently not implemented in FreeBSD but I need to understand the concept for a test I will be taking this week.

Answer (score 1):

It is as the [LWN](https://lwn.net/Articles/339337/) article states "when you write out a block, you lock it and iterate through the records of individual changes to this block. For each individual change whose dependencies haven't yet been satisfied, you undo that change to the block, and then write out the resulting block." However the part of visualizing this whole process was difficult and I wasn't able to wrap my head around it until I found this presentation paper by McKusick himself. This [page](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6410/2010fa/lectures/04-filesystems.pdf#page=44) specifically talks about rolling back changes to a deleted file to satisfy the ability to add a file. Afterwards the addition goes through and then we can perform the deletion.